# Is there a shorter (non-repetitive) way to create a list of the same float?

Tags: python, numpy, shorthand

Is it possible to write in shorthand the following:

```
x = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
```

as say

```
x = ([0.5]*12)?
```

Comment: Have you actually tried that?

Comment: Are you actually using `numpy`, or are you actually using lists as you've shown?  Because, what you have will work with lists, but not numpy.

Comment: Maciej is right, works like a charm mate!

Comment: @mgilson, will  `np.array(([0.5]*12))` not work?

Comment: I'm guessing that you were unable to test yourself to see if this syntax works, because you don't actually have an interpreter on your computer. This is fairly common, ex. when you don't have administrative rights to install programs. If so, an online interpreter should do in a pinch -- I like to use [Ideone](http://ideone.com/7s7eEm).

Comment: @PadraicCunningham -- There are LOTS of ways to do this with numpy.  `np.array([0.5] * 12)` should work ... `np.ones(12) * 0.5` should work as well.  I suggested `np.full(12, 0.5)` -- My bet is that is faster than using the `np.array` factory (but who knows?  You'd have to `timeit` to have any real data, and that seems like too much work :-)

Comment: @mgilson, you are right, I had already timed it,  it is much faster! I just thought I may have been missing something :)

Comment: I use Spyder for my IDE  @Kevin

Comment: `a = np.empty(12)a.fill(0.5)`  actually  seems the fastest

Comment: @PadraicCunningham -- I thought about that.  I'm actually surprised that `np.full` isn't that code exactly looking at the source, it's not much different but probably handles a few more corner cases or something ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using python's builtin lists, what you have will work:

```
x = [0.5] * 12
```

If you're using `numpy` and want to create an array, routine you're looking for is [`full`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.full.html#numpy.full)

```
import numpy as np
x = np.full(12, 0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

To put it into context, here is my code:

```
ambient_temp2 = [293,293,293,293,293,293,293,293,293,293,293,293,293,293,293,293,293,293]
Flow2 =     [0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]
LNG_range2 = np.array(([113]*18))
line_length = np.linspace(0.1,1,18)

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Temp':ambient_temp2, 'Flow': Flow2, 'LNG': LNG_range2, 'LengthOfLine': line_length})

def Tline_mod(ambient_temp2, LNG_range2, Flow2, line_length):

ha = 8.14
k = 0.0026
Do = 0.2
Di = 0.003175
L = line_length
F = Flow2
Ta = ambient_temp2
Ts = LNG_range2
pi = 3.14159265
Q = (pi*(Ta-Ts))/(((1/ha*Do))+(1/(2*k))*math.log(Do/Di)) * L
e = (Q*3600)/F

df3['Enthalpy Result'] = e
plt.plot(line_length, e)
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 12})
plt.annotate('Line Length Effects', xy =(0.4,25000))
plt.show()
print df3

print Tline_mod(df3['Temp'], df3['LNG'], df3['Flow'], df3['LengthOfLine'])
```

I tried the np.full method but it doesn't work.

EDIT ****

It worked.... I was just being careless. Thanks all :D

Answer (score -1):

When asking here, you should always first find a way to solve the problem on you own and show your work here. 
In your case, that is just running the bit of code and checking if there are any errors and if the list was created properly.

To answer your question, however, to create a list with *n* times the value *my_value* you can use the following for-loop:

```
my_list = [my_value for _ in range(n)]
```

[Source](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/python/3942-arrays-in-python.html)

Your code (`x = [0.5] * 12`) will also work, as python has the functionality for multiplying whole variables and not only the values of the variables.

EDIT:

Changed variable names, because of conventions. The loop variable is not used, so it is common to call it `_` as mgilson told me.

Comment: `x = ([0.5]*12)` works fine floats are immutable so there is no issue

Comment: FWIW, it's common in situations where you don't use the loop variable to call it `_`.  So, `my_list = [my_value for _ in range(n)]`.  It's also common to have `variable_names_like_this` rather than Java/Javascript style `variableNamesLikeThis`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the convention to call the loop variable '_'. Edited post to follow the conventions now.